# First answers queue and questions with closing votes

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, new-users

I just gained access to the "First answer" queue and reflected on something. It seems that questions which are borderline, that is, have received some negative feedback (I am not able to see other people's close votes, but I can guess from the question's comments), are more prone to receive *improvable* answers from newcomers, whereas standard questions do not show this correlation.

Have you considered to "block" questions with, say, 2 or more close votes for newcomers to answer? I think this would avoid trouble for both ends (moderation and newcomers), and it would not lead to an irreversible situation since:

- If the question is improved later, close votes can be retracted and newcomers answer it properly.
- If the newcomer earns reputation, he/she can also answer previously blocked questions with more experience, and not populate the "first answer" queue.

I'm pretty new myself so I don't know if this is even possible, but just a suggestion in case it is.